# EclipseLink @OneToOne relation CascadeType should not remove

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have two entity class, and there is a `@OneToOne` relation between them. There are also a foreign key in the database.

```
class Entity1 {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity1")
    private Entity2 entity2;
}

class Entity2 {
    @JoinColumn(name = "DB_FIELD_NAME", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_1_PK")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

As you can see there is `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` parameter. Of course, if I remove my entity1 object:

```
em.remove(entity1)
```

it's cascading to my entity2 and that object also removed from the database. My question is, how can I don't remove my entity2

What kind of `CascadeType` should I use?

Thank you!

Comment: Cascade delete is causing the delete to remove the referenced entity. Only set cascade options that you need- why are you using the cacade all option?

Comment: So if I don’t use any cascade type it won’t delete the child record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply nothing.
If you don't want to cascade, do not use cascade parameter, it's **optional**.

```
class Entity1 {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entity1")
    private Entity2 entity2;
}

class Entity2 {
    @JoinColumn(name = "DB_FIELD_NAME", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_1_PK")
    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    private Entity1 entity1;
}
```